# R parse unexpected symbol for alphanumeric values

Tags: r, parsing, symbols, alphanumeric

I am creating a network plot on some text corpus. I am creating the graph and then using igraph, ggraph to plot the graph.

```
tmp %>% 
  group_by(word) %>% 
  filter(n() >= 10) %>% 
  pairwise_cor(word, chapter) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(correlation), + correlation > 0.7) %>% 
  graph_from_data_frame() %>% 
  ggraph(layout = 'fr') + 
    geom_edge_link(aes(edge_alpha = correlation, edge_colour = 'gold'), 
    show.legend = F ) + 
    geom_node_point(color = 'lightblue', size = 2) + 
    geom_node_text(aes(label = as.character( name)), repel = T, colour = 'blue', parse = T) + 
    theme_void()
```

Error in parse(text = as.character(lab)) : :26:5: unexpected symbol 25: 968 26: 2594m

So I tried to do this:

```
parse(text = '49efv')
```

Error in parse(text = "49efv") : :1:6: unexpected symbol 1: 49efv ^

The issue is happening ONLY when the string begins with a number.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ it be an unexpected symbol? You can't have variable names that start with integers. What is it that you expect `parse` to do with it?

Comment: I don't think parse() does what you think it does. What are you trying to do? What do you have and what do you want as output? Please review guidelines on how to ask a question there [ask]

Comment: editied my question. is it better now?

Comment: `parse` tries to evaluate a string as R code. Your string isn't R code, so it doesn't parse. What happens if you make `parse = T` into `parse = FALSE`?

Comment: parse = F solves the problem. 
Also gsub('[[:digit:]]+' , '', name) instead of just name solves the problem. 

So R codes cannot start with a number hence the problem right?